# PyQt Qthread requestInterrupt() not changing isInterruptRequested()

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

I need to safely interrupt/stop a thread, and I am attempting to use requestInterrupt() to get a safe stop. I have been searching around google and stackoverflow, but it seems I cannot get it to stop the thread at all. It is not producing any errors, just moving on like I never made the request.

isInterruptRequested() does not change at all. It should be True when an interrupt is requested, but it is always false.

MRE of my code:

```py
import sys
from time import sleep

from pathlib import Path

#PyQt5 Imports
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(343, 362)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 301, 281))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.stopSearch = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.stopSearch.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopSearch.setObjectName("stopSearch")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.stopSearch, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.startSearch = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.startSearch.setObjectName("startSearch")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.startSearch, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.textEdit.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QCursor(Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.textEdit.setAutoFormatting(QTextEdit.AutoBulletList)
        self.textEdit.setUndoRedoEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setAcceptRichText(False)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Test Window"))
        self.stopSearch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop Task"))
        self.startSearch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Task"))

class contactPuller(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(contactPuller, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = searchWorker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self._connectActions()
        
    def _connectActions(self):
        self.startSearch.clicked.connect(self.searchStart)
        self.stopSearch.clicked.connect(self.searchStop)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.startSearch.setEnabled(True))
        
    def searchStart(self):
        self.textEdit.clear()
        self.startSearch.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopSearch.setEnabled(True)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def searchStop(self):
        self.textEdit.append('searchStop called')
        self.startSearch.setEnabled(True)
        self.stopSearch.setEnabled(False)
        self.worker.requestInterruption()
        self.thread.requestInterruption()
        
    def reportProgress(self, text):
        self.textEdit.append(text)

class searchWorker(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(QThread, self).__init__()
        
    def save(self):
        self.progress.emit("Save Call")
        
    def _terminate(self):
        self.progress.emit("_terminate call")
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            sleep(2)
            self.progress.emit(f'Interrupt reqested: {self.isInterruptionRequested()}')
            print(f'Interrupt reqested: {self.isInterruptionRequested()}')
            if self.isInterruptionRequested():
                    self.browser.quit()
                    self.save()
                    self.thread.stop()
                    self.thread.wait()
                    self.progress.emit('Stop Call')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    cntctChkr = contactPuller()
    cntctChkr.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

EDIT: Changed truncated snippet into "working" example

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante Just add a long running task, and set up a thread. Give me a few minutes to whip up "working" example code.

Comment: Added MRE. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subclassing QThread, but you're not using it as such, only as a simple QObject.

Any call to `requestInterruption()` is ignored if the thread *for which it is called* is not running (or is finished).

While you are running the `run` function from another thread, you're not running the `worker` thread.

The solution is simple: don't use another QThread, use the one you already have.

```py
class ContactPuller(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.worker = SearchWorker()
        self._connectActions()
        
    def _connectActions(self):
        self.startSearch.clicked.connect(self.searchStart)
        self.stopSearch.clicked.connect(self.searchStop)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.workerFinished)

    def searchStart(self):
        self.textEdit.clear()
        self.startSearch.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopSearch.setEnabled(True)
        self.worker.start()

    def searchStop(self):
        self.textEdit.append('searchStop called')
        self.stopSearch.setEnabled(False)
        self.worker.requestInterruption()

    def reportProgress(self, text):
        self.textEdit.append(text)

    def workerFinished(self):
        self.startSearch.setEnabled(True)


class SearchWorker(QThread):
    progress = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def save(self):
        self.progress.emit("Save Call")
        
    def _terminate(self):
        self.progress.emit("_terminate call")
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            sleep(2)
            interrupt = self.isInterruptionRequested()
            self.progress.emit(f'Interrupt requested: {interrupt}')
            print(f'Interrupt requested: {interrupt}')
            if interrupt:
                self.save()
                self.progress.emit('Stop Call')
                break
```

Comment: Thank you! It took me a moment to figure out what exactly changed here.

Comment: @Xlaits You're welcome! Basically, I just removed `self.thread` as it was redundant (and prevented the proper implementation of your subclass). I also removed the `finished` signal (since it already exists and is automatically emitted when `run()` returns) and the calls for `self.thread` in the worker (besides, remember that [`thread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread) is an existing function of all QObjects). PS: You may already know that, and you probably did it only for the example, but you're not supposed to edit files generated by pyuic.